# how to add the public ip to X509 certificate when access kubernetes api server

Tags: kubernetes

I am deployment a kubernetes v1.22.3 cluster using kubeadm, today when I access api-server from public domain, shows error like this:

```
2021/08/04 11:20:19 http: proxy error: x509: certificate is valid for 10.96.0.1, 172.29.217.209, not 107.124.83.31
```

`10.96.0.1` is my kubernetes cluster ip address, `172.29.217.209` is my host internal ip address. `107.124.83.31` is my public domain ip address. how to add the public ip `107.124.83.31` into the certificate so that I could access api server from public domain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you shoud add IPs and domains of APIServer to `certSANs` in `ClusterConfiguration` of kubeadm config and `kubeadm init --config=<kubeadm-config-file>`.

```yaml
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta2
kind: ClusterConfiguration
apiServer:
  certSANs: ['localhost','127.0.0.1'] 
  ...
```

Comment: Is it rebuild entire your cluster?